# integral of polynomials is $1$ or $ 0$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, analysis, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Consider the set of eigenvectors of a symmetric matrix $A$  with entries $a_{ij} = \int_{-1}^1 x^i x^j dx$. Theerefore we find an orthognal basis  $b=(b_0,..,b_n)$ , where $b_j \in \mathbb{R^{n+1}}$. We know that they are orthogonal, meaning $b_i^T b_j =0$ Assume that $||b_i||_2 = \frac{1}{\sqrt{v_i}}$, where $v_i$ is the corresponding eigenvalue.

Define $h_j(x) = \sum_{i=0}^n a_{ji}x^i$

I want to show that $\int_{-1}^1 h_j(x) h_i(x) dx =0$ and $\int_{-1}^1 h_j(x) h_j(x) dx =1$

If I plug it in, I cannot use the orthognality since I consider only the $j$ th component of each eigenvector. Can you maybe provide a hint?

Comment: The question doesn't work. If $A$ is the $(n + 1) \times (n + 1)$ identity matrix (which is symmetric), and $a_0, \ldots, a_n$ are the standard basis vectors, then all the eigenvalues are $1$ (so the $a_j$s satisfy all the requirements). But then, $h_j(x) = x^j$, which is not orthonormal with respect to the given inner product; the integrals don't come out right. For example, $\int_{-1}^1 h_0(x)h_2(x)\, \mathrm{d}{x} = \frac{2}{3} \neq 0$.

Comment: Ok maybe $A$ should no arbitary. Assume $a_{ij} = \int_{-1}^1 x^i x^j dx$

Comment: I edited my question. Does this help?

Comment: It does help. Some more context would be good too. What are you studying? This looks a lot like linear algebra (specifically, inner product spaces), though the tag is not present. Where did you come across this question? It might help figure out which techniques you're able to use.

Comment: It comes from a numeric background. But I know many linear algebra things. Maybe you can provide a hint?

Comment: Well, from your usage of "orthogonal" and familiarity with linear algebra, you may have heard of an inner product. The map $\langle f, g \rangle = \int_{-1}^1 f(x)g(x) \, \mathrm{d}x$ is an inner product on the space of polynomials of degree at most $n$. If $B = (1, x, x^2, \ldots, x^n)$ is a basis of this space, then $A$ is the [Gramian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gram_matrix) of $B$. See if you can prove, then use, the following nice property: $$(Av)_i = \langle x^{i+1}, v_1 + v_2x + v_3x^2 + \ldots + v_nx^{n+1}\rangle.$$

Comment: Does the property not read like this: $(Av)_i = <x^i, v_1+...+v_nx^n>$?

Comment: I am not quite sure how I can use that?